# does looking up the address components of a google place id use part of my quota?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

If I use the google places api and/or autocomplete, followed by looking up the result's place id to get the address components do I use more of my quota? Or is using the place id lookup "free" or at least included as part of my original lookup's quota usage?

I have tried looking in the documentation, but cannot find anything that mentions the google place id specifically.

Google recommends using the google places api for the lookup followed by looking up the place id to get the address components... but nowhere does it say if this additional lookup is "free" or if it will cost me additional google credits.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a place id lookup, you are sending a [place details](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) request. Even if you send it from Google Maps JavaScript API places library it will be counted as a place details request.

Typically, you will see something like `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails?2sen-US&8s...` in network activity of your browser when you execute a place ID lookup.

This request will consume your quota.

The documentation states that each web service request consumes your quota:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_quotacalc

I hope this clarifies your doubt!